# Changing font color in a table adding unwanted extra spacing

Tags: tables, fonts, spacing, color

I haven't been able to find a solution, so I'm hoping for any suggestions.  When I try to change the font color in my table, I get extra spacing above and below the lines with the color-changed font.  Any way to work around this?

```
\begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright}p{0.5cm}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{9cm}}
\ding{47}                & Test 1 \\
{\color{new}{\ding{47}}} & {\color{new}{Test 2}} \\
{\color{new}{\ding{47}}} & {\color{new}{Test 3}}\\
{\color{new}{\ding{47}}} & {\color{new}{Test 4}} \\
\ding{47}                & Test 5\\
\end{tabular}\
```

An image of what's happening:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `\textcolor` instead:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\colorlet{new}{red}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright}p{0.5cm}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{9cm}}
\ding{47}                & Test 1 \\
\textcolor{new}{\ding{47}} & \textcolor{new}{Test 2} \\
\textcolor{new}{\ding{47}} & \textcolor{new}{Test 3} \\
\textcolor{new}{\ding{47}} & \textcolor{new}{Test 4} \\
\ding{47}                & Test 5 \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or `\leavevmode` before `\color`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\colorlet{new}{red}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright}p{0.5cm}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{9cm}}
\ding{47}                & Test 1 \\
\leavevmode\color{new}\ding{47} & \leavevmode\color{new}Test 2 \\
\leavevmode\color{new}\ding{47} & \leavevmode\color{new}Test 3 \\
\leavevmode\color{new}\ding{47} & \leavevmode\color{new}Test 4 \\
\ding{47}                & Test 5\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Or for the lazy guys: `\begin{tabular}{>{\raggedright\mbox{}}p{0.5cm}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\mbox{}}p{9cm}}`

Comment: Thank you so, so much! Both solutions work perfectly for me

Comment: @GonzaloMedina The `\leavevmode` is particularly useful when using the array package to create row styles e.g.  `\rowstyle{\bfseries\leavevmode\color{red}}`. Thanks.

Comment: `\leavevmode` doesn't seem to work when applying `\color{red}` to the entire tabular environment using `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` before and after the tabular environment. Any suggestions?