How to fix beamer's \structure producing an unexpected vertical spacing?
Using the \structure command of the beamer package, I found the
following typesetting oddities.  \structure seems to add space
only in certain settings, for example, when using p columns in
tabular environments, or in X columns in tabularx environments,
or in algorithmic environments only when algpseudocodex is used.  See the following almost-MWE:
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tabularx,algpseudocodex}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    \hline \structure{test} & test
  \end{tabular}
  \begin{tabular}{p{1cm}l}
    \hline \structure{test} & test
  \end{tabular}
  \begin{tabularx}{2cm}{ll}
    \hline \structure{test} & test
  \end{tabularx}
  \begin{tabularx}{2cm}{XX}
    \hline \structure{test} & test
  \end{tabularx}
  \begin{algorithmic} 
    \Function{test}{...}
    \State test
    \State \structure{test} % no space added under "algpseudocode"
    \EndFunction
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{frame}
\end{document}

Is this is an error in the definition of \structure or in the way
how I use this command?
Either way, are there any workarounds? I'd prefer keeping tabularx
and algpseudocodex for my presentations.

basically a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121782/changing-font-color-in-a-table-adding-unwanted-extra-spacing

A MWE to replicate the problem could be
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tabular}{p{1cm}l}
    \hline \color{red}test & test
  \end{tabular}

\end{document}

As a workaround, you could use a simplified definition of the \structure macro which uses \textcolor:
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tabularx,algpseudocodex}

\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=red}
\renewcommand<>{\structure}[1]{\alt#2{\textcolor{structure.fg}{\usebeamerfont{structure}#1}}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    \hline \structure{test} & test
  \end{tabular}
  \begin{tabular}{p{1cm}l}
    \hline \structure{test} & test
  \end{tabular}
  \begin{tabularx}{2cm}{ll}
    \hline \structure{test} & test
  \end{tabularx}
  \begin{tabularx}{2cm}{XX}
    \hline \structure{test} & test
  \end{tabularx}
  \begin{algorithmic} 
    \Function{test}{...}
    \State test
    \State \structure{test} % no space added under "algpseudocode"
    \EndFunction
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{frame}
\end{document}



Thanks, Sam. Also for pointing to the other question. So, \structure doesn't apparently do anything fancy and can be redefined easily. Very good to know.

@mfg The original definition of \structure is a bit more complicated, but in most cases this simplified version should do just as well.

Ah, thanks. I've just checked, they look indeed more complicated. But your solution seems to work just fine for my purposes. Actually, omitting the \setbeamercolor line works as well.
